# How to modify Java JDK source related to GradientPaint classes (implements Paint Interface) in order to change from float to double precision?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision

I have never tried to modify anything so deep like the jdk itself, but I was wondering how hard or practical would that be for a specific task. The purpose is to experiment/test very high resolution image gradients with fine details, so color coordinate positions with better accuracy seems critical. Currently java gradient constructors accept float values only for coordinates.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html

Do you think it is possible to change those coordinate float references to double? Would it be just like changing minor parameters in source or something more complex?
Ideally those classes should support float and double at the same time (use somehow both contractors much like Path2D.Double Path2D.Float) but this is not a prerequisite for me, only the easiest way, just doubles. Performance is not an issue as images are static, no animations.

Considering the modular nature of java 17 LTS, what are the steps to follow for a task like this one, if possible? Any guidance will be much appreciated!

(javaFX as far as I can see support gradients with double precision, but I cannot use this for various reasons)

Comment: just out of interest, why do you want to do this?  I don't know that API, but it looks to be designed for handling color, which for most people is still 8bit.  hence I'm not sure why you'd want to go beyond a 32bit float!

Comment: You are right about the color, 8bit is ok in most cases, but... I am referring to point coordinates in x,y plane and not the color. There might be a chance that this one gives me random empty gradients in very "small" polygon fills, and the only reason I could imagine is the coordinate double to float casting. Other than this, I am not sure though, color "more bits" is something different, but might eliminate the so called "color banding" artifacts, which in case of java gradients, are more than obvious

Comment: I have managed to partially resolve the issue by bypassing a local coordinate system, there might be a chance that the origin of x,y plane was affected by the double to float conversion. I will keep the question alive, there are many similar issues about float/double precision in various forms for example in processing.org, https://blog.generativedarkroom.com/why-i-switched-from-processing-to-openrndr-b50c931d21ae

Comment: In the meanwhile I have tried to isolate related classes code from java 17 source, GradientPaint.java, RadialGradientPaint.java, MultipleGradientPaint.java, LinearGradientPaint.java, but I was not able to create a new version for either of them as there are some cross dependencies, abstract/privilege limitations  I could not resolve. But I guess someone who has a ready or access to a development system for all those kind of sources could probably do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was not the solution to this specific case, I have recompiled successfully all batik gradientpaint classes, those seem to be almost the same as native (I guess batik is the original source anyway).

e.g. org.apache.batik.ext.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
So this can be done through batik's source and then use those instead of native with "double" coordinates.